Why is TS not aware of the constraints of generic parameters?
const objectKeys = <T extends {},>(obj: T) => Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>;

const bigObject = {
    a: 1,
    b: '2',
    c: [3],
};
const smallOne = {
    a: 1,
    b: '2',
} satisfies Partial<typeof bigObject>;


// same as Object.assign(bigObject, smallOne)

// I can understand, `bigObject[key]` => `bigObject['a' | 'b']` => `number | string`, if `smallOne[key]` wants to assign to `bigObject[key]`, it must be `string & numer` => never
objectKeys(smallOne).forEach(key => bigObject[key] = smallOne[key]);
// err:                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

// Here I can't understand, the type T must be either 'a' or 'b', so why does it need attribute 'c'?
objectKeys(smallOne).forEach(<T extends keyof (typeof smallOne),>(key: T) => bigObject[key] = smallOne[key]);
// err:                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Type '{ a: number; b: string; }[T]' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; b: string; c: number[]; }[T]'.
//  Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: number; b: string; }' but required in type '{ a: number; b: string; c: number[]; }'.(2322)

(TS playground)
I am confused on the last line, why TS need attribute 'c' in smallone?
I expect objectKeys(smallOne).forEach(<T extends keyof (typeof smallOne),>(key: T) => bigObject[key] = smallOne[key]); can work properly, and do not throw error.

• Kyes is a distracting typo; could you fix it? • You're running into this issue with ms/TS#30769; TS only wants to allow assignments T[K] = T[K] where T and K are identical, if K is constrained to a union type. So you need to widen bigObject first, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

sure, I have fixed this typo. In this comment, the first two examples(function f1, f2) explain why objectKeys(smallOne).forEach(key => bigObject[key] = smallOne[key]); is not allowed, and i have already known; But the last two examples only talk about "index signatures" issues, so I'm still confused. And I find that: objectKyes(smallOne).forEach(<T extends keyof (typeof smallOne),>(key: T) => smallOne[key] = bigObject[key]); is allowed, it's also weird. Thank you in advance for your time

So, we can reduce your example to this playground. This is certainly caused by ms/TS#30769 (the only relevant change between TS3.3 and TS3.5). The exact reason why might not be spelled out there. TS doesn't like T[K] = U[K] unless U extends T (which is always safe). It complains when T extends U, even in the benign case where T only differs from U in properties unrelated to K. If you need an authoritative reason why, you could open an issue for it (using the more minimal example here). Otherwise, you'll get my description above. How do you want to proceed?

Well, it seems like the simplest rule is to remember: TS doesn't like T[K] = U[K] unless U extends T;  I guess the reason that TS doesn't support this is probably because of implementation complexity. I think your comment can be taken as the correct answer to this question! and, I'll go to the TS github repo and open an issue for it to get more details
